# Error securing a transaction Entity Framework "_dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction()"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to secure a transaction through Entity Framework. When I use `BeginTransaction`, ASP.NET throws an exception:

> The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

This is my code inside the repository

```
public async Task<EvaluationFormQuestionAnswer> AddScore(EvaluationFormQuestionAnswer evaluationFormQuestionAnswer)
{
    evaluationFormQuestionAnswer.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    evaluationFormQuestionAnswer.EvaluatorId = _identityService.Identity.CurrentAccount.Id;

    using (var transaction = _dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _dataContext.EvaluationFormQuestionAnswer.AddAsync(evaluationFormQuestionAnswer);
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            transaction.Commit();
            return result.Entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new ArgumentException("Error", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `CreateExecutionStrategy` instead of `BeginTransaction`? That's what the error message seems to be telling you to do.

Comment: Also, your error handling is not right. An ArgumentException should be used to specify a problem with an argument passed to the method. If you're not going to enhance the caught exception with any more details, you may as well just do `throw;` which will rethrow the caught exception and preserve the stack trace.

Comment: I don't remember instantiating anything like it, I just made this configuration of the code above as shown on microsoft website

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about with instantiating something. Please reread my comments.

Comment: I don't use CreateExecutionStrategy. I try to use BeginTransaction, but I receive this response

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that because you've shown that code to us. But if you read the error message, it seems to imply that you should be using CreateExecutionStrategy instead of BeginTransaction. I don't know much about this particular error, but it seems like something easy for you to try out.

Comment: Also SaveChanges() is _always_ in a transaction.  So if you don't have additional database operations you need to enlist, you can just omit the transaction handling.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var strategy = _dataContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            ...<Your Using Block>...
        });
```

Wrap it in the execution strategy as shown above and your code should work fine.